# C++ Maths With PerCent

Tags: c++

I am having an issue with the maths in c++. The IDE I'm using is Code::Blocks with GNU compiler. So, the problem is that when i ask for user input and the user give me a number greater than 10000 like 10001 etc. the system returns 6.9531e-308 as output! I don't know what this is.

```
#include <iostream>

double moneyBonus (double money, double& bonus);

int main ()
{
    double money, earnMoney, bonus;

    std::cin >> money;
    earnMoney  = money * (40.0/100.0);

    moneyBonus(money, bonus);

    std::cout << bonus << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

double moneyBonus(double money, double& bonus)
{
    if (money >= 0 && money <= 1000)
    {
        bonus = money * (3.0/100.0);
    }
    else if (money > 1000 && money <= 2000)
    {
        bonus = money * (5.0/100.0);
    }
    else if (money > 2000 && money <= 4000)
    {
        bonus = money * (7.0/100.0);
    }
    else if (money > 4000 && money <= 10000)
    {
        bonus = money * (8.0/100);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Solved! (I didnt find any button to flag it as solved)

Comment: Well, what value are you expecting and why?

Comment: You should return a value from function `moneyBonus` or change return type to `void`. This is not the reason for the problem though.

Comment: instead of `3.0/100.0` you can use 0.03 which will return exactly the same value. Otherwise use `(money * 3.0)/100.0`

Comment: there is no button to flag the question as solved, but you should accept one of the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you don't initialise the variable `bonus`. Also, your function `moneyBonus` does nothing if bonus is greater than 10000. Hence the output you see is the uninitialised value, which is a garbage value.

To fix it, either do

```
double bonus = 0; // or something
```

Or add an `else` case in your `moneyBonus` function like

```
else
{
  bonus = 0; // or whatever value your prefer
}
```

Also, either return the desired value from the `moneyBonus` function and use it, or change the type of the function to `void`.

Comment: According to existence of variable `earnMoney` `moneyBonus` most probably should return `money - bonus`

Comment: @Slava : Could be. I didn't go over the function in that aspect. Editing answer though.

Answer (score 1):

The variable "bonus" is not initialized for values of 10000 and above