# Output is either 6.9531e-308 or 0 (noob)

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I'm trying to write a program that will give the cost of a phone call based on when it starts/ends and how long it takes. Everything works fine, except for when it tries to actually display the cost of each call and the total cost at the end.

Every cost is listed as $6.9531e-308. Someone with a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33044199/c-maths-with-percent) resolved their issue by initializing the variable in question to zero but when I do that the program just starts listing every cost as $0.

The way I'm calculating the total doesn't seem to be working either, since when the cost is $6.9531e-308, the total comes out to $7.64841e-307 instead of $4.17186e-307. It's either multiplying one of the costs by 11 or it thinks there's 11 costs that need to be added up.

Here is the code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

ifstream fin("call_history.txt"); //read from a file

//int main
int main() {

    string temp;
    double total = 0.0;

    while (getline(fin, temp)) {
        istringstream s(temp);
        string token[3];
        int i = 0;

        while(getline(s, token[i], ' ')) { //split the string by spaces and store into token[0], token[1], etc.
            i++;
        }
        //token[0] stores the day of week
        //token[1] stores the time (i.e "14:32")
        //token[2] stores duration

        istringstream s2(token[1]);
        string time_values[2];
        i = 0;

        while(getline(s2, time_values[i], ':')) { //split token[1] by ':'
            i++;
        }
        //time_values[0] stores hour
        //time_values[1] stores minute

        //rename variables for readibility
        string day = token[0];
        int hr = atoi(time_values[0].c_str()); //atoi to convert string to integer

        int minute = atoi(time_values[1].c_str());
        int duration = atoi(token[2].c_str());
        double cost=0; //accumulator
        int start_time = (hr*60)+minute;
        int end_time = start_time+duration;
        int startzone, endzone;

        if (day == "Mo" || day == "Tu" || day == "We" || day == "Th")
            {
                day == "weekday";
            }
            if (day == "Sa" || day == "Su")
            {
                day == "weekend";
            }
    //assigning each starting time to a zone
            if ((day == "weekday" || day == "Fr") && (start_time >= 480 && start_time < 1080))
            {
                startzone = 1; //call starts on hours
            }
            if ((day == "weekday" || day == "Fr") && (start_time <= 480))
            {
                startzone = 2; //call starts before 8 am
            }
            if ((day == "weekday" || day == "Fr") && (start_time >= 1080))
            {
                startzone = 3; //call starts after 6 pm
            }
            if (day == "weekend")
            {
                startzone = 4; //call starts on the weekend
            }
    //assigning each ending time to a zone
    //this program will handle at most 3 zone changes in one call.

            if (day == "weekday" && (end_time >= 480 && end_time <= 1080))
            {
                endzone = 1; //call ends on-hours the same day
            }
            if (day == "weekday" && (end_time >= 1080 && end_time <= 1920))
            {
                endzone = 2; //call ends after 6 pm on the same day, before 8 am on the next day
            }
            if (day == "weekday" && (end_time > 1920 && end_time <= 2520))
            {
                endzone = 3; //call ends on-hours on the next day
            }
            if (day == "weekday" && (end_time > 2520))
            {
                endzone = 4; //call ends after 6 pm the next day
            }
            if (day == "weekend" && (end_time <= 2880))
            {
                endzone = 5; //call starts and ends on the weekend
            }
            if (day == "Fr" && (end_time >= 1440 && end_time <= 2880))
            {
                endzone = 6; //call goes from weekday to weekend
            }
            if (day == "Su" && (end_time >= 1440 && end_time <= 1920))
            {
                endzone = 7; //call goes from weekend to weekday off-hours
            }

        //Cost calculations
        //CALL STARTS ON HOURS
                if (startzone == 1 && endzone == 1) //call is entirely within on-hours
                {
                    cost = duration*0.4;
                }
                if (startzone == 1 && endzone == 2) //call starts on-hours and ends before 8 am the next day
                {
                    cost = ((1080-start_time)*0.4) + ((end_time-1080)*0.25);
                }
                if (startzone == 1 && endzone == 3) //call starts on-hours and ends on-hours the next day
                {
                    cost = ((1080-start_time)*0.4) + (840*0.25) + ((end_time-1920)*0.4);
                }
                if (startzone == 1 && endzone == 4) //call starts on-hours and ends after 6 pm the next day
                {
                    cost = ((1080-start_time)*0.4) + (840*0.25) + (600*0.4) + ((end_time-2520)*0.25);
                }
                if ((startzone == 1 && endzone == 6)) //call starts on hours friday and ends on the weekend
                {
                    cost = ((1080-start_time)*0.4) + ((360)*0.25) + ((end_time-1440)*0.15);
                }

        //CALL STARTS OFF HOURS
                if (startzone == 2 && endzone == 2) //call starts before 8 am and ends before 8 AM the next day
                {
                    cost = ((480-start_time)*0.25) + (600*0.4) + ((end_time-1440)*0.25);
                }
                if (startzone == 2 && endzone == 3) //call starts before 8 am and ends on-hours the next day
                {
                    cost = ((480-start_time)*0.25) + ((end_time-1920)*0.25);
                }
                if (startzone == 2 && endzone == 6) //call starts before 8 AM friday and ends on the weekend
                {
                    cost = ((480 - start_time)*0.25) + (600*0.4) + (360*0.25) + ((end_time-1440)*0.15);
                }
                if (startzone == 3 && endzone ==6) //call starts after 6 PM friday and ends on the weekend
                {
                    cost = ((1440-start_time)*0.25) + ((end_time-1440)*0.15);
                }
                if ((startzone == 3 && endzone == 2) || (startzone == 2 && end_time <= 480)) //call is entirely within off-hours
                {
                    cost = duration*0.25;
                }
                if ((startzone == 3 && endzone == 3)) //call starts after 6 pm and ends on-hours the next day
                {
                    cost = ((1920-start_time)*0.25) + ((end_time-1920)*0.4);
                }
                if ((startzone == 3 && endzone == 4)) //call starts after 6 pm and ends after 6 pm the next day
                {
                    cost = ((1920-start_time)*0.25) + (600*0.4) + ((end_time-2520)*0.25);
                }

        //CALL STARTS ON WEEKEND
                if (startzone == 4 && endzone == 5) //call is entirely within weekends
                {
                    cost = duration*0.15;
                }
                if (startzone == 4 && endzone == 7) //call starts on sunday and ends before 8 am monday
                {
                    cost = ((1440-start_time)*0.15) + ((end_time-1440)*0.25);
                }

        cout << setw(4)<< endl;
        cout << day << " " << hr << ":" << minute << " " << duration << " $" << cost << "\n";
        total += cost;

    }
    cout << setw(4) << endl;
    cout << "\tTotal $" << total << "\n";

}
```

Comment: 1. I do not want cost to show as 0, I want it to show as the cost of the call, as calculated by the appropriate formula
2. How do I floor a value?

Comment: Is it possible none of the if statements under cost calculation never get called so `cost` is always `0` which means `total` is always `0`? Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: Debugger.  Use a Debugger.  A debugger will help you execute each statement separately while *watching* values in variables.  Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to add an example of input, the expected calculation (how to figure out the cost) and the output your program gave to you instead?

Comment: Does the code you posted output zero, or a very small positive number? You need to focus on one problem at a time, not what a different version of your code would do.  Also, yes, debugger.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem isn't (entirely) with your formulae, but with the inherent limitations of floating point numbers**

The key issue here is that between any two numbers, there are an infinite number of real numbers (an *uncountably infinite* number of them, in fact), and only a finite amount of space in a double to represent them.  So there *will* be rounding errors.

Furthermore, since they're stored in base 2, not base 10, there will exist numbers that really seem like they *should* be exactly representable, but aren't.  The standard example being `0.1`; there is no finite representation of that in base 2.

Consider the following:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main() {
    double x = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        x += 0.1;
        printf("%.20f\n", x);
    }
}
```

This will output something like the following:

```
0.10000000000000000555
0.20000000000000001110
0.30000000000000004441
0.40000000000000002220
0.50000000000000000000
0.59999999999999997780
0.69999999999999995559
0.79999999999999993339
0.89999999999999991118
0.99999999999999988898
```

Now, the last number should be 1.0, which *is* exactly representable, but by that point, the rounding errors have added up, so we get something slightly different.  That's what's happening in your code.  There are *tiny* rounding errors that add up to 6.9531e-308, when the value would have been 0 if no rounding had happened.  The easiest solution is just to print in a format that forces it to round the *final* answer off to a point where it's accurate.  For instance, if we change `printf("%.20f\n")` to `printf("%.1f\n")` in the above example, it will print exactly the numbers you would expect.  And in your example, just forcing it to *not* use scientific notation will be sufficient to make it round to 0.

```
double x = 6.9531e-308;
printf("%e\n", x);
printf("%f\n", x);
std::cout << x << "\n";
std::cout << std::fixed << x << "\n";
```

will output:

```
6.953100e-308
0.000000
6.9531e-308
0.000000
```

If you want to understand the gritty details of how floating point numbers work (which I recommend you do eventually even if you aren't at that stage of your education yet), this paper is the standard reference: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

**Addendum:**

Also, you do `day == "weekday";` where you mean `day = "weekday";` in a couple places, which is why it's near 0 at all.  Which is probably a more *significant* issue, albeit a much less interesting one to talk about.

Comment: Thank you. So basically, what I have to do is add something in front of the cout line so it only prints something that's been rounded already?

Also, when I try to change day == "weekday" to day = "weekday" it gets interpreted as an error and I can't compile the file.

Comment: @Soulsoaker99 There are two different kinds of rounding happening here.  The first is the *rounding error* that happens any time a number can't be exactly represented in the binary floating point format.  Then there's the rounding that happens when you print; it clearly isn't going to print an infinite number of digits if you try to print a repeating decimal, nor will it print hundreds of digits for long but finite sequences.  What std::fixed does is tells it to not use scientific notation.  (continued...)

Comment: (...continued) 6.9531e-308 is also rounded; it's actually going to be 6.95317234782378423780432e-308 or something, but you called setw so it only gets to print 4 digits after the decimal point.  If it didn't use scientific notation, there would be hundreds of zeros before any nonzero digit, so it gets rounded to 0. As for why it isn't compiling, what compiler are you using and what's the error?  The only error I see is that you should be including <cstdlib> for atoi.